# Make @MockBean return new object for each test case

Tags: java, spring, mockito, mockmvc

**Description**:
I am writing integration tests where ApplicationContext is used. To simulate database failure I am using @MockBean for DAO layer.
Every test case using @MockBean reference, and referencing the same object in memory(double-checked with debug).

I need different behavior of mockbean for each test case in test suite.

**Problem**:
I found strange situation when first test case ran with mock stubbed in second test case, hence the @MockBean returns incorrect result.

I want every test case to use newly created bean, to avoid modification of shared resource.

**Question**:

Is it possible to make @MockBean a prototype?
So every test case will use its own @MockBean and its stubbing won't affect other test cases.

Comment: Try adding more context to your question. What do you use `@MockBean` for exaclty? Using `@Mock` instead might solve your problem.

Comment: I need to setup ApplicationContext hence @Mock isn’t applicable here

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that @MockBean already does that. Have you tried for sure using @MockBean?

Take a look at the documentation [MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html), you can set the 'reset' mode MockitoReset.BEFORE